# EF 6 delete fails with The select list for the Insert statement contains more items than the insert list

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

My EF Remove fails with the above statement. The table (Product) has a single primary key (ProductID). Running SQL Trace produced the following SQL that causes the failure:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[Product] WHERE ([ProductID] = @0)',N'@0 int',@0=620895
```

Full error statement:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure t_del_Product, Line 8 The select
>   list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert
>   list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT
>   columns.

Other similar Removes work just fine. My EDMX is fully updated against the DataSource (SQL Server 2012)

Any ideas? Anyone? Anyone?
Thanks!

UPDATE: I should have tried this earlier, but I get the same error even with a simple:
DELETE FROM Product Where ProductID = 620895
So, it is not EF.

Comment: Can you post the code/LINQ that is doing the delete, thanks

Comment: is there a trigger on the table calling `t_del_Product`?

Comment: @Ric. Thanks much. I had assumed (erroneously) that t_del_Product was being generated by EF. After I saw your comment I went looking with: Select * From Sys.Objects Where Name = 't_del_Product'. Like I should have to begin with and found it. Man, do I hate triggers :)

Comment: It looks like the sp is being called (possibly) when a delete occurs on `dbo.Product` and is producing your error. Just look on the table and see if there are triggers defined on it.

Comment: I am not to familiar with stackoverflow. How do I mark your answer as the correct on?

Comment: converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

It looks like the sp is being called (possibly) when a delete occurs on `dbo.Product` and is producing your error. Just look on the table and see if there are triggers defined on it.

If indeed there is a trigger on the table calling this SP, then this is likely your issue and you should look into fixing the SP.

Comment: That would be my first thought as well.

Comment: For me, it was an audit table that didn't have the newly created column. I added the column to the trigger and the audit table and it all worked.

Comment: it happens to me that I had a trigger inserting in a history table and didn't have newly created column in history table

Comment: triggers can be useful, but, most of the time they are evil